# Make text line up with CSS styled horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of text in a `<h1>` above a horizontal rule. The text does not line up exactly with the rule unless I apply `margin-left: -4px` to the `<h1>`. This seems a bit hacky to me. What is the correct way to line them up?

Example, the text is a few pixels to the right (dotted line added to highlight that the text and rule are not lined up):

Horizontal line starts at 0 whereas TEST starts at 4Px.

[image]
Code:

```
<h1 style="margin-left: -4px">TEST</h1> (without the -4 they do not line up)
<hr class="styledHorizontalRule" />

.styledHorizontalRule {
    height: 1px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;

    background-color:blue;

    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work when put into fiddle. Please, explain what you want to do, because I think there is a better way.

Comment: Have you checked padding?

Comment: Are you using anything like bootstrap? a lot of times there is default padding and margin added to certain elements. (also #blue isn't a valid color, use blue or a hex color code)

Comment: Some other style might be applying to your TEST . Check in Dev tools whether any other styles are applying apart from  what you apply.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it is a margin/padding issue. I didn't see the problem being replicated in the given example, but try this:

```css
h1 { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

.styledHorizontalRule {
    height: 1px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;

    background-color: blue;

    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>TEST</h1>
<hr class="styledHorizontalRule" />
```